# Setting focus on a sub form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two sub forms embedded in control (the one that looks like a set of folders allowing you to change from tab to tab.. Sorry I don't know the name in English)..
Both sub forms are embedded on one sheet, I would like that immediately after executing a routine, I wrote on one of the subforms, that the set focus then goes to the other sub form.
For some strange reason I can't get it to work. The sub form and field I'm trying to go to are frmObjectives03 and Effective_date.

I tried:

```
Forms!frmObjectives03!Effective_date.Form.SetFocus
```

but it doesn't work.

I would appreciate any insight.

Thank you,

Comment: try `Forms!frmObjectives03!Effective_date.SetFocus`

Answer (score 0):

The control you speak of is a Tab control.

Because `frmOjective03` is opened as a subform, it is not part of the Forms collection. Instead you can use `Forms!MainForm!frmObjectives03.Form!Effective_date.SetFocus` from anywhere, or `Me!frmObjectives03.Form!Effective_date.SetFocus` from within the main form or `Me.Parent.Form!frmObjectives03.Form!Effective_date.SetFocus` from the sibling subform.
If these are not working for you, please check the name of the subform control in your main form (because it may be Child17 instead of frmOjective03). Open the main form in design view, click on the subform ONCE and look in the Properties->Other->name.